# Asynchronus $.post inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript infamous Loop problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem)

I am having troubles trying to access a variable inside a `$.post` function.

The value of the variable `a` inside the function is always the same: **7**. But outside it, it increases as I want.

Why is this happening? How can I do a loop for a `$.post` function?

```
for(var a=0; a<7; a++){
    console.log(a); /* increasing value */

    $.post("http://"+ document.domain + "/posts/user/xxxxx",
        function(departments){
        console.log(a);  /*value of 7*/

    });
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: ref: [Javascript infamous Loop problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem) (there should be a *close* option, just for this ever recurring question, no offence!)

Comment: Oh yea, just make 7 Ajax requests in a row. Your server will be fine. `:P`

Comment: @Sime, is the only way as far as I know to obtain 7 arrays of different data from the DB...

Comment: @Steve Wait, why not make the server script get all the data from the DB, and then return it in one response. Yes, I'm a genius! `:P`

Comment: @Steve: I don't see any difference between the seven requests, did you forgot to send `a`? Anyway, you might restructure your API so it could return the 7 arrays in one single request

Comment: @Bergi, I just didn't publish all the code so I reduced it and of course, the URL call has no sense now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either give each for iteration it's own scope, or use `$.ajax` and the `context` option.

```
for(var a=0; a<7; a++){
    (function(a){
        console.log(a); /* increasing value */

        $.post("http://"+ document.domain + "/posts/user/xxxxx",
            function(departments){
            console.log(a);  /*value of 7*/

        });
    })(a);
}
```

with `$.ajax`...

```
for(var a=0; a<7; a++){
    console.log(a); /* increasing value */

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://"+ document.domain + "/posts/user/xxxxx",
        type: "POST",
        context: a,
        success: function(departments){
            console.log(this);  /*value of 7*/    
        }
    });
}
```